# Weblogic session replication

Tags: session, weblogic, replication

I can't seem to get Weblogic's session replication to work.
I have set-up in my web.xml such that all requests require Admin credentials:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>redirect</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>
            /login.jsp
        </form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>
            /login.jsp
        </form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

In my weblogic.xml, I have setup:

```
<session-descriptor>
    <persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</persistent-store-type>
</session-descriptor>
```

My test case is with two managed servers.

1. Navigate to my webpage.
2. Bring down one managed server. (The one that I am currently connected to)
3. Failover occurs and I am asked for my credentials.

I expect failover to occur seemlessly, without having me to relog in.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable session replication option in Weblogic admin console...

Logon to admin

```
console -> goto cluster -> goto advanced -> tick Session replication.
```

Note : It's not a good practise to touch .xml files to change any property....